can't start Libreoffice on Kubuntu 22.04
I had Libreoffice 24.2 that I installed from the .deb packages on the libreoffice website. I got a notification that a new version was available, so I downloaded and installed the 24.8 one. I then noticed that instead of overwriting 24.2 with 24.8 like it has every previous time when I upgraded it, it installed them separately. Whenever I opened a document it was still using the old version.
I then uninstalled 24.2 on the command line through apt, and after that when I tried to start 24.8 I can't get any libreoffice program to start. When I enter:
libreoffice --writer

I get this error:

I tried uninstalled and reinstalling from the debs provided here:
https://www.libreoffice.org/donate/dl/deb-x86_64/24.8.1/en-US/LibreOffice_24.8.1_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz
by uncompressing the files and entering:
sudo dpkg -i *.deb

but I still get that error. How can I fix it?

Try the following:
Open a terminal.
Run on it.
   sudo apt remove --purge libreoffice*

   cd ~/Downloads

   wget https://ftp.nluug.nl/office/libreoffice/libreoffice/stable/24.8.1/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_24.8.1_Linux_x86-64_deb.tar.gz

   wget https://ftp.nluug.nl/office/libreoffice/libreoffice/stable/24.8.1/deb/x86_64/LibreOffice_24.8.1_Linux_x86-64_deb_helppack_en-US.tar.gz

   for x in *.tar.gz; do tar xfv $x; done

   sudo dpkg -i LibreOffice_*/DEBS/*.deb


Try the technique suggested in Libreoffice printing is always in landscape format - the one where you ignore the failing version and point /usr/bin/libreoffice and /usr/bin/soffice to the version you installed.
